# Where should Puppet Resources be Placed?

Tags: windows, puppet, flyway

I have the following `flyway.pp` Puppet class which installs Flyway onto Windows machines. It copies two files into the installation folder.

```
class rehan::flyway {
    package { 'flyway':
        ensure      => latest,
        provider    => chocolatey
    }

    file { 'C:/Program Files/flyway/ntlmauth.dll':
      ensure => 'file',
      source => 'puppet:///modules/rehan/manifests/ntlmauth.dll',
    }

    file { 'C:/Program Files/flyway/drivers/sqljdbc4.jar':
      ensure => 'file',
      source => 'puppet:///modules/rehan/manifests/sqljdbc4.jar',
    }
}
```

The above modules lives at `modules/rehan/manifests/flyway.pp`. I have placed the two files `ntlmauth.dll` and `sqljdbc4.jar` along side it but it seems a bit messy. Is there a standard directory or location where these files are normally placed? Also, how can I refer to these files using a relative path, I use `puppet:///modules/rehan/manifests/ntlmauth.dll` because I've seen it somewhere but that does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be a bit confusing.

In your module's directory, you should have a subdirectory named 'files' and all files you want to be copied/installed somewhere need to be put there.

The confusing bit is that when addressing one of the objects stored there, you **don't** mention 'files' in the path!

So,

```
source => 'puppet:///modules/rehan/sqljdbc4.jar'
```

picks up the jar file from the following path:

```
/etc/puppet/modules/rehan/files/sqljdbc4.jar
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason why puppet:///modules/rehan/manifests/ntlmauth.dll doesn't work is that it maps the path to /etc/puppet/modules/rehan/**files**/manifests/ntlmauth.dll which doesn't exist.

You can not reference an object located in your manifests directory using puppet:///